# Why aren't there three slayers?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer

When Buffy dies at the end of season 1, Kendra is activated. When Kendra dies, Faith is activated. Why doesn't Buffy's death at the end of season 5 activate a third slayer?

Comment: Presumably a slayer can only "die" and start a new slayer once. Otherwise you could take Buffy into the ER and kill and resuscitate her a few hundred times and have a very large army of slayers!

Comment: @Nick Or just have Willow turn all Potentials into Slayers. That seems like less work than killing Buffy over and over again.

Comment: @SocioMatt - even Willow wasn't sure she'd be able to do that. And it took the power of the scythe to pull it off.